# Get nearest business name/type by address or GPS coordinate

Tags: ios, web-services, api, gps, reverse-geocoding

I'm writing an iOS application and it would be very handy to know the way to find a nearest business name (and especially business type, such as restaurant/hotel/store etc.) by a GPS coordinate, or at least by an address.

So just curious, is there such API/Web service out there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, it seems like I have to answer my own question. I didn't try it out in code, but the answer is here:
http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places/

Unfortunately there seems to be a cap on how many times Google places API can be called (for free), i.e. 1000 times per day (for the same API_key.)

Answer (score 2):

Yes

[Bing](http://www.bing.com/toolbox/bingdeveloper/)

[Google Places](http://www.google.com/places/)

[Yahoo Geo Technologies](http://developer.yahoo.com/geo/)

I'm sure there are loads more to be found with a quick google

Comment: I appreciate your knowledge of the current GeoCoding sites, but I was expecting a more relevant answer...

Comment: They all offer APIs to get businesses via location

Comment: Do you know for sure? Say, in case of Google, can you give me a specific API to do that?

Comment: From the doc - which is a click away from the link I gave you

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=harbour&sensor=false&key=AIzaSyAiFpFd85eMtfbvmVNEYuNds5TEF9FjIPI

I've used 1 of these in anger (bing). Played with places, and have no experience with yahoo other than to note they offered an api. SO, I'm pretty darn sure.... :-$

now frankly, I'd like to be marked back up please ;-)